# Curl issue with cert verification

Tags: curl

Mac OS Mojave appears to have a default version of curl v7.54 installed.
It appears to give the following error messsage when run against a server that had a recent change of expired certificate to a valid certificate.

> curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired
>
> - SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired

This issue persists even after presenting the latest *--cacert ~/cacert.pem* file

However, curl v7.7 does not report any error messages, which is the correct behavior as verified by Chrome/Firefox.

Since Mac OS has the older version of curl installed by default this issue appears to be a problem for a lot of users. Is this a known issue on older versions of curl? Are there any known fixes or workarounds for v7.54?

Comment: Is this against a server you manage?

Comment: yes. It's against a server that I have access to.